# Expanding array capacity

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was thinking of ways to make an array larger quickly in C++ and I came up with this:

```
// set up arr1
int *arr1 = new int[5];

// add data to arr1
arr1[0] = 1;
arr1[1] = 2;
arr1[2] = 3;
arr1[3] = 4;
arr1[4] = 5;

// set up arr2
int *arr2 = new int[10];
arr2 = arr1; // assign arr1 to arr2

// add more values
arr2[5] = 6;
arr2[6] = 7;
arr2[7] = 8;
arr2[8] = 9;
arr2[9] = 10;
```

Is this even safe? I worry that this will cause some strange behavior and that arr2 is just an int[5] array and you're now overwriting data that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: What book are you learning C++ from?

Comment: just experimenting, no book here. I was considering methods to make expanding the size of the array faster. This is obviously an ill-guided approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `arr2 = arr1;` leaks memory, and all the following `arr2[...]=` lines invoke undefined behavior as they access the array of 5 ints outside of its bounds.

To do what you wanted to do, replace `arr2 = arr1;` with `std::copy(arr1, arr1+5, arr2);`  (example program: https://ideone.com/3Rohu)

To do this properly, use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Finally, someone talking about the STL! :-) +1

Comment: @PeterK: Or, in fact, about the C++ Standard Library. *ducks*

Comment: @Tomalak: Quack! Showing my age... :-(  [but +1 anyway!]

Answer (score 8):

NO.

`arr2 = arr1;`

Does not do what you think it does!

There is already something in the STL for this, it's called `vector`.

---

For the sake of completeness.. :)

`arr2` before the assignment held the address if the start of the array of 10 items you allocated. After the assignment, rather than copying the *contents* the block addressed by `arr1` (which I guess is what you wanted to do), the assignment merely changes the address that `arr2` holds to the address that `arr1` holds (i.e. start of the 5 item array), for the rest of your code, this has two consequences:

1. You no longer have the address of the block of 10 items you allocated, so you have no way of releasing that block - hence you have a memory leak (should your program continue to operate)
2. Though you initially allocated 10 items for `arr2`, by the assignment, you're now addressing a block that only has 5 items, and accessing anything outside of that block of 5 (i.e. indexes 5 onwards) is likely to end in nasal daemons paying a visit with a very large cricket bat - or you may get lucky...

So what can you do:

1. Use `std::vector<int>`, one if it's design features is to take this kind of burden away 
   from you (unless you're interested in implementing another container), if that's the case
2. Use a copy operation to correctly copy the contents rather than assign the addresses, as suggested, use `std::copy` - or others, such as `memcpy` (prefer `memmove` - it's a little slower but is well defined for overlapping blocks etc.)

Comment: I thought so. This was more for academic purposes (replicating the behavior of a vector).

Comment: @Tomalak, was in a rush, had to run home, more important things to do (i.e. play with my son)... anyways, now that he's a sleep... I see I'm too late to the game...

Comment: It's never too late! I think there are badges for posting answers to really old questions :)

Answer (score 5):

This leaks memory, because you are assigning pointers.

```
int *arr2 = new int[10];
arr2 = arr1; // this does not assign the values
```

The second assignment makes `arr2` point to the array `arr1`. You loose the array you have previously allocated, and can never delete it.

To avoid this, use an `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe at all. When you said `arr2=arr1;` you didn't copy any of the data across, you just reassigned a pointer. Now the memory you allocated with `int *arr2 = new int[10];` has been leaked, and `arr2` points to the original 5-element array, and when you start saying things like `arr2[5] = 6;` you are writing beyond the end of that array and all hell may break loose.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe that's actually a memory leak. You're not doing anything with arr2 you just ended up setting arr2 to the address of r1, remember in c and c++ theres no bounds checking so you're overwriting another stackframe by doing that

Answer (score 2):

> Is this even safe?

No

> arr2 = arr1; // assign arr1 to arr2

`arr2` is also pointing to first index element of `arr1`. And by doing it, `arr2` looses the location where it was earlier pointing to returned by `new`. So, there is **memory leak**.

Use std::vector instead to expand the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other comments which are correct. The reason why you will leak memory is that you have replaced arr2 pointer that pointed to allocated memory for arr2 with arr1 pointer. Now arr1, arr2 point to the same thing, the array of 5 elements. When you try to clean up with delete operator, you can only clean up the 5 element array since the pointer to 10 element array has been overriden.